# Find all subsets of a set that sum up to n

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, subset, partitioning

Here is the code that I came up with:

```
static void findNumbers(int[] list, int index, int current, int goal, String result)
{ 
  if (list.length < index || current>goal)
          return;
   for (int i = index; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (current + list[i] == goal)   {
         System.out.println(result + " " + String.valueOf(list[i]));
       }
       else if (current + list[i] < goal) {
           findNumbers(list, i + 1, current + list[i], goal, result + " " + String.valueOf(list[i]));
        }
   }
}
```

Call it using:

```
findNumbers(array, starting_index, current_sum_till_now, target_sum, "");
```

Can someone help me figure out the time complexity of this code I believe its exponential.

What is the most optimal way to solve this problem? Is it using backtrack?

Comment: Maybe `O(2n*log(n))` ?

Comment: Order doesn't have constants, it's about growth.

Comment: One of the classic NP-complete decision problems, [Subset Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), is reducible to this problem, so the problem is NP-hard and you are very unlikely to find a correct solution with polynomial time complexity.

Comment: @Sarkae i've added a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been pointed out that I've done a mistake. I were multiplying the complexities of recursive calls while I should have added them. So  `C(N) = C(N-1) + C(N-2) + ...`. The same would then apply to `C(N-1)`, `C(N-2)`, etc. This means that the complexity isnt' `O(N!)`.

This have made me thinking on the algorithm from another point of view. It is checking every single possible subset. Since there are `2^N - 1` possible subsets (the empty subset is not taken into account), then the complexity is `O(2^N)`, which I think is your original bet.

Comment: Worst case would be a list with N zeroes and the goal of zero. In such a case, every subset is also a solution.

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi I think your complexity analysis is bit off though reasonable mistake, First C(N)!= N*C(N-1), its C(N) = C(N-1)+C(N-2)+C(N-3)...C(0) then C(N-1) = C(N-2) + C(N-3)....C(0) hence C(N) = 2*C(N-1) hence C(N) = O(2^N)  not O(N!)

Comment: @VikramBhat You're right. I should't multiply the complexities. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code to work on the principle "if a number is good - add it; disregarding any condition skip current number". In this case the code will be:

```
static void findNumbers(int[] list, int index, int current, int goal, String result)
{ 
  if (list.length <= index || current>goal) // I've added the "=" which is missing in your code.
          return;
  if (current + list[index] == goal)   {
      System.out.println(result + " " + String.valueOf(list[i]));
  }
  else if (current + list[index] < goal) {
      findNumbers(list, index + 1, current + list[i], goal, result + " " + String.valueOf(list[i]));
  }
  findNumbers(list, index + 1, current, goal, result);
}
```

In this case the complexity will be `O(2^n)` which is better for `n=>5` then `O(n!)`.
As it was pointed out, the complexity is reduced if the array is sorted. Meaning you can put the 2nd recursive call inside the `else if` because you will be sure that all number that follow are greater then the current `list[index]` meaning there is no use skipping this value because all following branches from this call will not generate any valid subsets.

In this case the worst case is `O(2^l)` where `l` is either the index of a number that is greater then your goal and is in your array, or `n` if such a number doesn't exist.

The call should be: `findNumbers(list,0,0,goal,"")`

Comment: I think you missed out the for loop as there is no declaration for variable i

Comment: @Sarkar you could have looked at the second recursive call, it is `index` instead of `i`, not it is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

As has just been pointed out it is worse than N^2, in fact it looks like O(N!). You will save a bit as you can exit on some of the loops early but the degree of saving would depend on how fast possibilities get eliminated.

In terms of a more optimal solutions you are going to struggle, this is an excellent case for recursion as any loop based construct is going to be horrific. You may be able to save some time by pre-sorting your data so larger values are first and hence you reach target faster (this will essentially eliminate anything in your list that is larger than your goal immediately). After the too-big entries are eliminated I am not sure if it will help directly as you still need to compare everything with everything but it might improve the processor branch predictions.

Comment: It's not `O(N^2)` as he's recursively invoking the same function more than twice (provided list contains more than 2 entries)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using dynamic programming and knapsack analogy : -

1. Sort the set in ascending order
2. Evaluate subset till `list[i] <= N`
3. Solve Knapsack for sack of capacity N and items having value and weight as their `list[i]`
4. If at end knapsack capacity N == max profit then atleast one solution subset exists.
5. retrace all solutions for knapsack using cost matrix and get all the solution subsets.

**Time complexity:** `O(|S|*N + K)  |S|- length of set and K is number of subsets.`   This is a pseudo polynomial time algorithm.

**Note:** Problem being NP-hard no polynomial time algorithm is yet discovered.

**Edit:-** Retrace solution from boolean matrix

```
void retrace(int n,boolean[] solution,int target) {

   if(n>=0) {

        if(table[target][n-1]) {

            solution[n] = false;
            retrace(n-1,solution,target); 
        }

       if(table[target-numbers[n]][n-1]) {

            solution[n] = true;
            retrace(n-1,solution,target-numbers[n]);
       }
   }

   else {
       printf("\nsubset:-\n");
       for(int i=0;i<solution.length;i++) {

            if(solution[i]) {
                printf(number[i]+" ");
            }
       }

   }


}



  Call : - retrace(numbers.length-1,new boolean[numbers.length],target);
```

Comment: This backtrack is where I am stuck at. I have formed a boolean matrix which tells whether you can find subsets of the set that sum upto n. http://ideone.com/OlOG16 However I cannot seem to backtrack the original subsets themselves. Any implementation would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are n and solution[] in this snippet?

Comment: Solution is just boolean array to store subset solutions, if solution[n] = true means nth element is included in subset. n is the number element that can be in the solution which initially is total number of items

Comment: The table matrix is of the form boolean [][] table = new boolean [target + 1] [numbers.length + 1] ; so the line if(table[n-1][target]) is giving an Exception. Also the number array runs till n so this step for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) is showing exceptions