# How to store values in a vector with nested functions

Tags: r, function, recursion, nested, store

Following with this question [R: from a vector, list all subsets of elements so their sum just passes a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623156/r-from-a-vector-list-all-subsets-of-elements-so-their-sum-just-passes-a-value)

I´m trying to find a way to store the values given by the print command in a vector or matrix but I can´t find any way to do it. 
The code is:

```
v<-c(1,2,3)
threshold <- 3 # My threshold value

recursive.subset <-function(x, index, current, threshold, result){
  for (i in index:length(x)){
    if (current + x[i] >= threshold){
      print(sum(c(result,x[i]))) 
    } else {
      recursive.subset(x, i + 1, current+x[i], threshold, c(result,x[i]))
    }
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

I tried this code but I just get the last sum

```
recursive.subset <-function(x, index, current, threshold, result){
  for (i in index:length(x)){
    if (current + x[i] >= threshold){
      return(sum(c(result,x[i]))) 
    } else {
      m<-recursive.subset(x, i + 1, current+x[i], threshold, c(result,x[i]))
    c(m,m)
    }
  }
 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
v<-c(1,2,3)
threshold <- 3 # My threshold value


recursive.subset <-function(x, index, current, threshold, result){
  for (i in index:length(x)){
    if (current + x[i] >= threshold){
      store <<- append(store, sum(c(result,x[i])))
    } else {
      recursive.subset(x, i + 1, current+x[i], threshold, c(result,x[i]))
    }
  }
}

store <- list()
inivector <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0) #initializing empty vector    
recursive.subset (v, 1, 0, threshold, inivector)
```

Comment: Wow!!! this code does exactly what I want!! Thanks a lot!! I tried to vote but I don´t have enough points yet! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your solution is the position of "return" statement. The solution could be:

```
recursive.subset2 <-function(x, index, current, threshold, result){
  m <- NULL
  for (i in index:length(x)){
    if (current + x[i] >= threshold){
      m <- c(m, sum(c(result,x[i]))) 
    } else {
      m <- c(m, recursive.subset2(x, i + 1, current+x[i], threshold, c(result,x[i])))
    }
  }
  return(m)
 }
```

Comment: It works fine for me:  
`ans <- recursive.subset2(v, 1, 0, 3, 0)  
> ans 
[1] 3 4 5 3
> ans <- recursive.subset2(v, 1, 2, 2, 5)
> ans
[1] 6 7 8`