# Expected value of the difference between a sum of variables and a threshold

Tags: r, sum, subset, mean

I had a custom deck consisting of eight cards of the sequence 2^n, n=0,..,6. I draw cards (without replacement) until the sum is equal or greater than the threshold. How can I implement in R a function that calculates the mean of the difference between the sum and the threshold??

I tried to do it using this [How to store values in a vector with nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107568/how-to-store-values-in-a-vector-with-nested-functions) 
but it takes ages... I think there is a way to do it with probabilities/simulations but I can figure out.

The threshold could be greater than the value of one single card, ie, threshold=500 or less than the value of a single card, ie, threshold=50

What I have done so far is to find all the subsets that meet the condition of the sum greater or equal to the threshold. Then I will only substract the threshold and calculate the mean.

I am using the following code in R. For a small set I get the answer quite fast. However, I have been running the function for several ours with the set containing the 56 numbers and is still working.

```
 set<-c(rep(1,8),rep(2,8), rep(4,8),rep(8,8),rep(16,8),rep(32,8),rep(64,8))
recursive.subset <-function(x, index, current, threshold, result){
  for (i in index:length(x)){
    if (current + x[i] >= threshold){
      store <<- append(store, sum(c(result,x[i])))
    } else {
      recursive.subset(x, i + 1, current+x[i], threshold, c(result,x[i]))
    }
  }
}

store <- vector()
inivector <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0) #initializing empty vector    
recursive.subset (set, 1, 0, threshold, inivector)
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting an [r] question it's often useful to provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). When asking questions like this, share what you've tried, even if it didn't work, so we've got something to start with.

Comment: Hi, sorry I´m new on stackoverflow. I edited the question to show what I have done so far. Probably my approach is "brute force" but I can´t figure out how can I improve it.

Comment: Are you solving the same problem as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623156/r-from-a-vector-list-all-subsets-of-elements-so-their-sum-just-passes-a-value)?

Comment: Yes, this is the link that is posted in the question that I point here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107568/how-to-store-values-in-a-vector-with-nested-functions the code I posted here is the code you pointed Pierre with some modifications, however, for a big set (in my case 56) it has been running for several hours. For a small set the code works perfect but not for a big set. I think is because the permutations are around 56! / 23!

Comment: @ph33 Does it suffice to do, say, 1 million random draws or does it have to be every possible combination? Because I wrote a script that can do 100k draws per second, but I'm not entirely sure if that is what you're looking for. It does allow you to estimate the mean difference.

Comment: @Laterow simulations will be much appreciated, I think with simulations what is necessary to do is to take N samples of the deck and find the mean of the sum, am I right? However, is there any way to find the exact solutions? THANKS!!!

Comment: @ph33 see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to get an exact solution, simply because there are so many possible combinations. It is probably better to do simulations, i.e. write a script for 1 full draw and then rerun that script many times. Since the solutions are very similar, the simulation should give a pretty good approximation.

Ok, here goes:

```
set <- rep(2^(0:6), each = 8)
thr <- 500

fun <- function(set,thr){
    x <- cumsum(sample(set))
    value <- x[min(which(x >= thr))]
    value
}

system.time(a <- replicate(100000, fun(set,thr)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.10    0.00    1.09

mean(a - thr)
# [1] 21.22992
```

**Explanation**: Rather than drawing a card one at a time, I draw all cards simultaneously (`sample`) and then calculate the cumulative sum (`cumsum`). I then find the point where the cards at up to the threshold or larger, and find the sum of those cards back in `x`. We run this function many times with replicate, to obtain a vector of the values. We use `mean(a-thr)` to calculate the mean difference.

Edit: Made a really stupid typo in the code, fixed it now.
Edit2:  Shortened the function a little.